# fsnode, ssnode on MiKTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex

I am trying to create a bipartite graph using tikz, however, it doesn't seem to recognize the keys fsnode and ssnode on my Windows MiKTeK installation (works fine in Ubuntu).

Line:

```
\foreach \i in {$a$,$b$,$c$,$A$,$B$}
  \node[fsnode,on chain] (f\i) [label=left: \i] {};
```

Error:
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/ssnode' and I am going toignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... }

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the definition

I had this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,every node/.style={draw,circle},node distance=2mm, baseline=(s$A$)]
```

In order for it to work you have to specify fsnode and ssnode styles as well:

```
fsnode/.style={},
ssnode/.style={},
```